# PHP failed to open stream: No such file or directory ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])

Tags: php

I using xampp to do some php scripts. To test it local, the path is "http://localhost/shopping".

**index.php**

```
<?php include 'view/header.php' ?>
<?php include 'view/home.php' ?>
<?php include 'view/footer.php' ?>
```

It works ok.

**login.php**

```
<?php include 'view/header.php' ?>
<?php include 'view/home.php' ?>
<?php include 'view/footer.php' ?>
```

then i got error for login.php

```
Warning: include(view/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\view\login.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'view/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\view\login.php on line 2

Warning: include(view/home.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\view\login.php on line 3

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'view/home.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\view\login.php on line 3

Warning: include(view/footer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\view\login.php on line 4
```

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'view/footer.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\view\login.php on line 4

**index.php and login.php are in the C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping**

**header.php, home.php and footer.php are in C:\xampp\htdocs\shopping\view**

I searched many posts on SOF. i also tried

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

But for some reason or another, it doesn't work.  I think it's something simple but I just cant get it right.

Comment: just a possibility, is header.php is header.php and not header.php.txt (if the extension is hidden)

Comment: yes, its header.php . not txt file

Comment: did you put here your full index.php and full login.php ?

Comment: The answer to your problem is here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`include 'view/header.php'` doesn't work within `login.php` because that file is already in the `view` folder.

change your includes to always use full paths instead. The right path depends on the value of your document root but it's likely one of the following:

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/view/header.php';
```

Or

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/shopping/view/header.php';
```

This way the same include statement will work from all files.  You won't need to change paths based on where you're including from.

Comment: no. it doesn't work. i get the same error. it shortage of "shopping"  .  Warning: include(C:/xampp/htdocs/view/header.php) . If i change to include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/shopping/view/header.php'; <- this one is hard coding. I want soft coding thats working.

Comment: More generally there is a troubleshooting checklist for this problem here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36577020/failed-to-open-stream-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: What is with hosting when path with $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] doesn't work? It mean it exist in variable and path is made properly but it work only by IP or website name.
Is this server configuration?

Comment: @arrowman run a php script that just does: `printr($_SERVER)` and examine what is printed. Maybe you will find another array key you can use instead of `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for the same purpose.

Comment: @BeetleJuice thanks. But generally I do nothing and it started to work. Provider is changing OS on servers, maybe it is a reason:/ Since one moth there are crazy things with servers...
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to include from same folder so just use file name

```
<?php include 'header.php' ?>
<?php include 'home.php' ?>
<?php include 'footer.php' ?>
```

Comment: this way is hard coding. What i want is soft coding. any idea?

Comment: Untill you change your folder structure, I think its not hard coding. BTW what do mean by `soft coding` ?

Comment: when we download those open source and upload to server or test it locahost, we only fill in $db_host;  $db_name;  $db_user_name;  $db_pass;  , but we dont change those files in the header right?  so the same thing apply to my question.